# Need help with proof

Tags: probability

I am trouble proving $P(a\cap b)\ge P(a)+P(b)-1$

$P(a \cup b)=P(a)+P(b)-P(a \cap b) $

so

$P( a \cap b)= P(a)+P(b)-P(a \cup b)$

I am not a student.

Comment: use $P(a\cup b)\le 1$

Comment: No probability can be greater than 1 and therefore subtracting 1 make the quantity smaller then subtracting P(a U b).

Comment: If P( a u b)<=1 then P(a u b) +P(a u b)’ <=1. ?

Comment: I thought of using the p(a)+p(a)’=1 so P(A’)=1-P(A) Prior was a typo

Comment: @larrymintz  Please add the self-study tag. Also, this question gets asked periodically, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126901/how-to-prove-pa-cap-b-geqslant-papb-1

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

$P(a\cup b)\le 1\\\Rightarrow0\le 1-P(a\cup b)\\\Rightarrow 0\le1-[P(a)+P(b)-P(a \cap b)]\\\Rightarrow 0\le 1-[P(a)+P(b)]+P(a\cap b)\\\Rightarrow P(a)+P(b)-1\le P(a\cap b)$

Comment: More simply, $$P(A)+P(B) - P(A\cap B)  = P(A\cap B) \leq 1 \implies P(A) + P(B)-1 \leq P(A\cap B)$$ merely by moving $P(A\cap B)$ and $1$ to the other side of the inequality